# Compiler cannot find file but 'follow symbol under cursor' can

Tags: qt

After resolving the previous issues another seems to have reared it's head:

I have various directories in my pro file and a header file I am including has the format:

```
#include <ting/tong.hpp>
```

which when added to one of the paths in my pro file arrives at the correct file.  I can open it by right clicking and selecting 'follow symbol under cursor'.

If I enter the full path for the file then it compiles but this does not help as the header file I am including still contains a reference to it and I cannot change that file.

*Why would the find function be able to find the file but the compiler not?*

Answer (score 1):

You state:

> I assumed that if I provided the include directories in INCLUDEPATH it
>   would be able to find the headers but it is not. The only way I seem
>   to be able to fix it is to explicitly include the header file it
>   cannot find in the mainwindow file - surely this is not what I should
>   be doing?

Yes, this is exactly what you should be doing. In your `.pro` file, you include directories where your header files can be located:

```
INCLUDEPATH += ../third-party/fooProject/include
```

And then in your source code files, the files you want to include, typically in the `.h` file of your class:

```
#include <foo/foo_object.h>
```

This would include the header at `../third-party/fooProject/include/foo/foo_object.h`

Comment: What's not working? The process you describe as "the only way I seem to be able to fix it" is exactly what you are *supposed* to do. Unless I'm not understanding your problem, in which case you need to clarify your question and include some code samples.

Comment: Sorry, I wrote the question on wordpad and copied it over and in transition I left out the actual issue I was having - have edited the question so it actually asks the question